# How can I change the text style?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing

There are algorithms to change the forms of words, to define the subject of the text, as well as the definition of his style (literary, business, scientific, etc.). Do you have any ready ideas or solutions with the help of machine learning methods to change the text style?

Comment: It would be interesting to add relevant references about these algorithms you mention

Comment: This seems like a *hard* problem. First off, what do you mean by style? This seems ill defined. Second, do you have prior experience with NLP? You need to know that it is still a growing field, and there are no magic bullets: things like text summarization are nice, but is a much easier problem than understanding the contents of an entire document and rephrasing it.

Comment: @Auberon, for example, to change the form of words in the Russian language there is a great pymorphy library for Python. Due to the peculiarities of the Russian language, to change the forms of words there is very relevant. To define the text style will fit a simple linear classifier trained on a large corpus of documents.

Comment: @jmite, for example, it is easy to show the difference in text style on the sentenses, "Bye", and "Best regard, goodbye". They have the same meaning, but the first is suitable for informal communication, and the second is used more for formal. Yes, I have initial experience in NLP. Now I'm interested in is this problem. Perhaps, if there is at least some inclinations of ideas.

Comment: This seems to be either a *very* broad reference request, or an invitation to a brainstorming session. Neither works well as a question here. Community votes, please: too broad?